# How can I have a cancel button code run even if field validators are not satisfied?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, button, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form to register new users for my site and their are required field validators on the page.

I want to include a cancel button that redirects the form to the main page but unless the required field validatiors are satisfied it will not run the code when the cancel button is hit.

How can I have the code for the cancel button run even if the form is not fully filled out??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the property "ValidationGroup" applied to the fields you want to validate, so one button can cause validation in one group and other button cause validation in another group provided the buttons have their validation groups set with the same name.

If you want the cancel button to not validate at all, set its property "causesvalidation" to false

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:button id="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
    Text="Cancel" />
```